# How to write a parquet file using Spark df.write.parquet with defined schema. - pyspark

Tags: json, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, parquet

I am converting JSON to parquet file conversion using df.write. In my JSON file all my columns are the string, so while reading into dataframe I am using schema to infer and the reason for that no of columns in the file also keep changing. While writing to parquet I do not want to write them as the string instead I want some columns to change to date and decimal. I know we can select and do casting in the column level in the df select before capturing to another df. I do not want to do it since I have 300 columns in the file and program work based on parameter. Is there a way we can have them in the file as schema and do it.

example:

JSON read schema:

```
read_schema = StructType([
    StructField("event_name"              , StringType(), True),
    StructField("dollar_balance"          , StringType(), True),
    ])
```

Parquet write schema:

```
write_schema = StructType([
    StructField("event_name"              , StringType(), True),
    StructField("dollar_balance"          , DoubleType(), True),
    ])
```

Maybe a long question. Help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should select columns with `cast` and after you can bind the rdd of dataframe to `write_schema`. For example:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, DoubleType

spark = SparkSession\
        .builder\
        .appName("Write parquet")\
        .master("local[*]")\
        .getOrCreate()

sc = spark.sparkContext

df1 = spark.read.json("/path/to/json-file.json")

write_schema = StructType([
    StructField("event_name", StringType(), True),
    StructField("dollar_balance", DoubleType(), True),
])

spark.createDataFrame(
    df1.select(df1["event_name"], df1["dollar_balance"].cast(DoubleType()).alias("dollar_balance")).rdd,
    write_schema).show(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below.

```
  df.write.option("schema",write_schema).parquet(savepath)
```

hope it helps you.

Comment: Hi, I am trying this but It does not work, I am reading a parquet file that all variables are String, I want to put them all to float and integer, but when I write the new parquet the schema it is all string @Amar

Comment: You would need to cast the dataframe into relevant type and then map it to relevant schema.